# How to create a route for www.website.com/profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm coding a website like a platform where we can access the user profile from the following URL:

www.mywebsite.com/DanielVC

The controller that has the details about the profile is the following

- **Controller**: Perfil
- **Action**: Perfil

I already have the following Route for all application:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I already tried to create the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Perfil",
  url: "Pages/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this BEFORE (above) the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Perfil",
  url: "{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also, this will result in every route to be redirected to *Perfil* route. You must create a redirection in that action if a username is not found (e.g. mywebsite.com/randomuserthatdoesntexist) and/or other routes (mywebsite.com/contact).

**EDIT**

Example for your method

```
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if (matchesOtherRoute(id))
            RedirectToAction("OtherAction", "OtherController");
        if (!userExists(id))
            RedirectToAction("NotFoundAction", "ErrorController");
        // Do other stuff here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Perfil",
   url: "Pages/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Perfil", action = "Perfil", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);